# css hamburger menu for drop down navigation

Tags: html, css, menu

I've got a simple fixed nav bar, one of the list elements has a drop down hover.

**The problem** - The dropdown navigation has made it difficult for me to apply a **hamburger menu when the screen reaches a certain width**.

Initially, I tried to create a small menu div which would be hidden and then displayed at a certain width, this unfortunately didn't work.

I am honestly lost at how to do this.

Here is the code - here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGZWbP?editors=1100#0)

CSS -

```
    *, *:before, *:after { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }

 /* clear fix */
 .c-f::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  ul, ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

  .large-trunk {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1700px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  .inline-block-container > * {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
  }

/* Grid Units */
.col-1 {width:100%;}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Links  ------------------*/

a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ffd800 !important;
}

#menu-menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity: 0.6; 
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;  
}



/* Typography ------------------*/

html {
  font-family: 'Avenir Book', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.35em;
}


/* Navigation  ------------------*/

.header-menu {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  display: block;
}

.main-menu {
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 5rem;
}

.home-logo-container {
  float: left;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#menu-menu {
  text-align:center;
  padding-right: 0.6rem;
}

.sub-menu-item {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sub-menu:hover .sub-menu-item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}



/* mobile nav ----------------*/
.sm-logo {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="header-menu col-1">
  <!-- .mobile-only-logo -->
  <div class="sm-logo">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="main-menu large-trunk float-container">
    <div class="home-logo-container">
      <a href="#" class="home-link">
            Rare Select &emsp;
          </a>
    </div>
    <!-- .main-navigation -->
    <nav id="site-nav" class="main-nav float-container">
      <div class="menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-menu" class="inline-block-container">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="#">Info</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-item">
              <li>
                <a href="#">About us</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">T's & C's</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Find us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Newsletter</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**To clarify** - I simply need a method using css or jQuery that will show a hamburger menu at a smaller screen width.

Thanks

Comment: use media query

Comment: This isn't an answer specific to your code, but here's how I use `@media` to show the ☰ menu: https://github.com/center-key/hamburger-menu

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-bootsnipp" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" onclick="openMenuNav()">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">Rare Select</a>
        </div>

        <div class="menunav " id="menuNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#">Info</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-item">
          <li>
            <a href="#">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">T's & C's</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Find us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Newsletter</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
            </ul> 



        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Try this.. Hope this can help to solve your problem

Comment: Yes, I'm not using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without jQuery or JavaScript. All you need to use are CSS media queries. Media queries allow you to only show content when certain conditions are met. In this case, your viewport width must fit certain constraints.

The basic format for a media query is:

```
@media (/* Condition */) {
  /* CSS for when condition is met. */
}
```

If you run the following code snippet, the media query causes the hamburger menu to only appear when the screen is less than 768px wide. This is because once the width is 768px or greater, the media query is satisfied, so the CSS inside runs, and sets the `display` property to `none` for the image.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/1200px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png">
</body>
</html>
```

You can read more about media queries on the MDN.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries